# Google search API. Filter license

Tags: google-search-api

I want to search images using google API under specific licenses. But looking on the API documentation I can't understand how to use it properly.
I want to search:

- free to use or share, even commercially
- free to use, share or modify, even commercially

In the documentation I see

- cc_publicdomain
- cc_attribute
- cc_sharealike
- cc_noncommercial
- cc_nonderived

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list

Can someone tell me what my request should be look like?

Comment: Have you done the research? At http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.ch/2010/04/restricting-by-licenses-now-available.html: "For a full list of the attribute combinations for each type of license, perform an appropriately restricted search on Google Image Search's advanced search and take a look at the as_rights parameter in the URL on the results page."

Comment: @CindyMeister I tried it, but unfortunately advanced search doesn't use that parameters from API doc, I still seeking for the answer

Comment: I just need to know  what each parameter means? There no description for them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Official site of creative commons](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/#licenses) contain a description of each CC license types.
  You can use "cc_publicdomain", "cc_attribute" and "cc_sharealike" like "**free to use, share or modify, even commercially**" 
 and "cc_nonderived" like "**free to use or share, even commercially**". 
 
To set license in the request you can use "rights" parameter and pass target license types by url encoded comma.
 
Like in this request:

```
    GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=swollen+members+night+vision&cx=004646395488064118990%3Aachgbwsn6na&rights=cc_publicdomain%2Ccc_attribute&searchType=image&fields=items&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Also you can try online "any" google  service [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/) and create usable to you requests [here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/customsearch/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list)